# Change timezone using DateTime doesn't change it

Tags: php

I am trying to change time according to timezone. I am getting time and timezone from DB, time looks like this `2017-02-23 12:37:19` and timezone is according to [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php). I don't think the datetime has wrong format. But problem is that it doesn't convert the time from DB timezone, to timezone that I want to convert It.

```
$time = new DateTime($user['date'], new DateTimeZone($user['timezone']));
$user['date'] = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: You never actually change the timezone. You only set it for the date you already have.

Comment: Can I get a hint how do I return time from different timezone ? I can't seem to find it in docs

Comment: [DateTime::setTimeZone()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do so.

```
$time = new DateTime($user['date'], new DateTimeZone($dbTimeZone));
//use $dbTimeZone as the timezone from which you want to convert to your user timezone

$time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($user['timezone']));

$user['date'] = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sets the time zone, try this:

```
$user['timezone'] = 'Europe/Berlin';
$user['date'] = '2017-02-24 10:24:08';
$dbTimeZone = 'America/Vancouver';
$date = new \DateTime($user['date'], new \DateTimeZone($user['timezone']));
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($dbTimeZone));
$sConvertedDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $sConvertedDate;
```